# Why does adding a resistance in parallel decreases the circuit total resistance?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

Why does adding a resistance in parallel decreases the circuit total resistance?

Before you close the questions a duplicate, please read further: I *know* the classic explanation for this, and I think it's bogus. The classic explanation goes: "you add a new path for the current to flow, *of course* resistance is gonna be less" - but wait a second. You add a new path by adding a *wire*, not by adding a resistance. Therefore I would expect the total resistance to go down when adding a new wire "in parallel" with the rest of the circuit. I would then expect the resistance to go UP when adding a new resistor on that wire.

The "new path" answer doesn't make sense because it conflates the wire with the resistors. The new path is a wire. The new resistor is not a wire.

I am definitively not looking for a mathematical explanation, as I understand them. I am looking for an intuitive or "process" explanation, that is I want to know what's going on exactly and why the circuit behaves like it does. An explanation of why my "path analogy debunking" is wrong is also welcome.

Comment: If you want more traffic to get past a point on a highway, then you can increase the average speed or add an extra lane. So add a wire ie extra lane. Any wire **is** a resistance. Unless you add a superconductor, but I don't think you have one of those.

Comment: but the wire IS a resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what Ohm's Law states:

'At constant temperature, the current flowing through a conductor is directly proportional to the potential difference applied across its ends'.

If 'I' is the current and 'V' the potential difference

I ∝ V

I = V / k where 'k' is a constant determined by the material of the conductor, its length and its cross-sectional area.

'k' is known as the Resistance of the conductor, designated by the letter 'R' with 'Ohm' as its unit.

'1/k' is known as the Conductance of the conductor, designated by the letter 'G' with 'Mho' as its unit.

I = V / R = G . V

A resistor is a conductor made of a specific material and having a specific length and specific cross-sectional area.

Hence the classic explanation of 'a new path for the current to flow', with respect to resistors in parallel, is valid.